# Xamarin IoS 12 update: WKWebView custom renderer issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview, custom-renderer

I'm facing with a very weird issue with a Xamarin Forms application on IoS after the latest OS update. Basically this application uses a WebView renderer to navigate a company's intranet portal which has NTLM authentication. I implemented the web renderer to handle the authentication process and it was working fine till few week ago but after Apple's last update the webview has stopped working. 
Unfortunately there is no error code, exception or explicit message from the SDK, and the authentication process is working (I can see it from the logs), by the way the webview's content is all blank. 
I have tried to navigate to other websites (with no authentication) too (bing.com, google.com, xamarin.com) but the issue was still there.

Anyone has some suggestion or hint?

**UPDATE**

After a deep investigation I've finally found the problem! Actually it seems that after the deprecation of UIWebview when using a custom renderer to handle authentication scenarios you cannot skip the HTTP 200 response (as suggested before) otherwise the component won't load the html contents!

So this is what I had before in my custom renderer:

```
public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationResponse navigationResponse, Action<WKNavigationResponsePolicy> decisionHandler)
    {
        var url = navigationResponse?.Response?.Url;
        if (url == null) return;

        if (navigationResponse.Response is NSHttpUrlResponse)
        {
            var resp = navigationResponse.Response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
            if (resp.StatusCode == 200) return;
            HandleHttpResponse(resp);
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);

        }
        else if (navigationResponse.Response is NSUrlResponse)
        {
            //todo handle this case too if we want to open excel files in webview
            //UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Cancel);
        }

    }
```

and this is what I have changed:

```
var resp = navigationResponse.Response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
//if (resp.StatusCode == 200) return;
HandleHttpResponse(resp);
decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);
```

Just commenting the if for StatusCode 200 and let contine with decisionHandler it works... Very very weird!

Comment: Apple WebView API is deprecated, you need to use in your xamarin as WKWebView.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/WebKit.WKWebView/ for your reference

Comment: Hi Harjot, I'm already using WKWebView

Comment: Glad you have found your solution.